# Undo / Reset AllowSetForegroundWindow() calls

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to undo a call to `AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY)`?

The Big Picture:

- I want a single process of my exe running at a time.
- To achieve it, the processes communicates with each other using named pipes & if a process already exists, its window has to be brought into front.
- To be able to do this, the latest process must set `AllowSetForegroundWindow()` with the existing process id.

  - I do not want to fetch the process id (sorry for my laziness), so what I'm planning to do is: 1. call `AllowSetForegroundWindow()` with ASFW_ANY 2. Just in case some error occurred, undo the call to `AllowSetForegroundWindow()` so that others cannot steal focus from my process.

In simple words, I want to allow other processes to steal focus from me, in a particular time window only...

Any one faced similar issue earlier, and found any workaround?

Also, please let me know if you have any better suggestion / alternative...

Comment: You can get rid of the `AllowSetForegroundWindow` call entirely. When the existing process wants to take focus, it asks the latest process for it. If no request comes in, then the latest process does nothing.

Comment: @RaymondChen I didn't get it... If a request comes in, what should the latest process do?

Comment: You say that the two processes (call them A and B) are already communicating with each other, and you have A call `AllowSetForegroundWindow` just in case B wants to call `SetForegroundWindow`. Instead, just have B tell A, "Please call `SetForegroundWindow` on this window for me."

Comment: oh.. I didn't know a process can call `SetForegroundWindow()` on windows from different process. Will this bring the window to front? Or flashes in the taskbar? I'm of opinion it'd just cause the window to blink in taskbar, but I'll give it a try...

Comment: If a process has set-foreground permission, it can set foreground to any window it wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the target process (presumably including "any") will lose the ability to steal focus from you the next time you call `AllowSetForegroundWindow`.

In other words, it sounds like you can have only one such permission active at a time.

It follows that you should be able to cancel the permission by calling with some non-existent ID, or perhaps your own process ID. This is theory, however, I haven't tested it.

I'd personally just send the target process ID over the named pipe.

Comment: I tried by setting NULL as parameter, and it didn't work... I'll try with own process ID and will update...

Comment: My pipe communication is a bit restricted (non-technical reasons).. Giving own process id as parameter is working as expected... Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your primary requirement is to have only one instance of your application running at a time. If everything else you describe is only subservient to this requirement, and not part of some grander scheme, there is a simpler way to achieve that.

You can create a global named mutex when your application starts. All other instances will see this mutex as set, and simply quit immediately. Here's the quick and dirty of it:

```
// Multiple instances detection
HANDLE my_mutex = ::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "Global\\MyCuteFluffyMutex" );

int create_mutex_error = ::GetLastError();
bool already_running =
          ( my_mutex && ( create_mutex_error == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ))
       || ( create_mutex_error == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED );

if ( !already_running ) {
  // Run my application
}

::CloseHandle(my_mutex);
```

For more exhaustive info on `CreateMutex` and its parameters consult the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Though that is the main aim, my application logic gets complicated when the processes are in different desktops (i.e; different user spaces). For that reason, I've started using named pipes..

Comment: If instead of `Global` you prefix the mutex name with `Local` it will only be visible to other processes in the current session, and not across desktops. Instances on other desktops will be unaware and unaffected.

Comment: Let me explain why I said complicated:
- I want to restrict to single process at global level, but in a slightly different way.
- Assume user A launches the process, when the executable is also running in user B's space. So, the process of A requests the process in B to quit, i.e; in some cases, I want the new process to take control from the already existing process.

Comment: I see. If you already have your solution and it is working well, good. If not, I still think there is a simpler way, using global named event instead of mutex. Let me know if this interest you, and need me to elaborate.

Comment: I already have a working solution with named pipes, which is good for now.. Thanks for the assistance.. :)